# How to determine the output of jupyter notebook cells?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Cell1 outputs only 222, but Cell2 outputs 111 and 222. What's the difference?

Cell1

```
    In [1]: 111
            222
    Out[1]: 222
```

Cell2

```
    In [2]: print(111)
            print(222)
    Out[2]: 111
            222
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPython prints the value of the last expression in a cell, except if the value is none or if the expression is followed by a semicolon (;).

222 is the last expression in cell1, so it is printed.

The second cell prints two values to stdout; `print()` returns `None`, which IPython refrains from printing.